# T-SQL - How to loop and build declare variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to loop on the number of selected codes and assign the code description to a declare variable starting from @language_desc_1 to @language_desc_30.

So based on the data below. if I only have 2 languages flagged for display only 2 will be assigned not 3.

We use a label tool that is data field driven.  So I need to be able to assign variables.

The goal is to build a string of data with the Data Fields so that the label is reading the correct data.

The Products_Descriptions table looks like this:

```
8332    05  US  LARGE GREEN CHAIR   1   Y
8332    05  MX  SILLA VERDE GRANDE  2   Y
8332    05  CN  大綠色的椅子  3   N

DECLARE
@language_desc_1 nvarchar(100),
@language_desc_2 nvarchar(100), 
@language_desc_3 nvarchar(100),
@language_desc_4 nvarchar(100),
@language_desc_5 nvarchar(100)

BEGIN
select
    @language_desc_1 = case when a.RowNum = 1 then a.Language_code else null end,
    @language_desc_2 = case when a.RowNum = 2 then a.Language_code else null end,
    @language_desc_3 = case when a.RowNum = 3 then a.Language_code else null end,
    @language_desc_4 = case when a.RowNum = 4 then a.Language_code else null end,
    @language_desc_5 = case when a.RowNum = 5 then a.Language_code else null end
from
    (
    select
        Language_code, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Sort_Code) RowNum
    from
        Products_Descriptions
        where Display_On_Label_Flag = 'Y'
    ) a
END

select @language_desc_1
select @language_desc_2
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are wanting, but it the smells like maybe you are trying to do something... not the best way. Can you explain more about what this code is attempting to accomplish. Like what's your end game here?

Comment: Hi JNevill,  The end result would be looping on each products_descriptions code and assigning  language_desc_1 = "LARGE GREEN CHAIR" and language_desc_2 = "SILLA VERDE GRANDE" .

Comment: I get that, and it would be a challenge (if not impossible) to dynamically refer to a variable name while assigning it a value. Generally in programming this is what we use Arrays for. My question, though, is what are you going to do with those `language_desc_N` variables once you get them loaded. This feels very much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ooh... Sorry.  I will be creating a text file to send to a different server. SET cmd = '(echo '+facilityCode+' && echo '+productID+' && echo '+productDescription+
     ') >c:\Robert\TestExample.txt'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output

Comment: If that's your end goal, why do you need the 30 different variables?  Your comment doesn't mention how they will be used.

Comment: This is a terrible design, and t-sql isn't designed for it at all.  Maybe you should ask for help doing what you think you need this for.

Comment: The information will be store on a label.  The label could display up to 30 product descriptions in different languages. The label product that we uses is driven by Data Fields.  So I need to have the 30 variables to assign to the Data Fields if we every need 30.

Comment: However I did change the design to work like this,  select
 language_desc_1 = case when a.RowNum = 1 then a.Language_code else null end,
 language_desc_2 = case when a.RowNum = 2 then a.Language_code else null end,
 language_desc_3 = case when a.RowNum = 3 then a.Language_code else null end,
 language_desc_4 = case when a.RowNum = 4 then a.Language_code else null end
from
 (
 select
  Language_code, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Sort_Code) RowNum
 from
  Products_Descriptions
  where Display_On_Label_Flag = 'Y'
 ) a

Comment: I know this is not a good design.  And I know SQL is not design to change variables "language_desc_XX".  I am just giving an example on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need to `select` individual variables in individual `select` statements?  Why can you not just pass through your whole dataset as one?  If that is not possible, what is stopping you having 30 `select`1 statements that just `select` based on an ordered `row_number` of your `language` data?

Comment: When you say you are *just giving an example on what I am trying to do* could you tell us what you are ***actually*** trying to do with the table design, some test data and a desired output?  It seems this contrived example is mis-communicating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to develop something for users in my company that only know SQL to make changes to a stored procedure without developing a C# dll. I decided to just create a c# dll to handle this. We only have a couple of C# developers.

Thanks for your help everyone.